# Wait for many asynchronous tasks to finish. Generally, how to run millions of transactions fast

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, java-ee-6

Let's say there is a millions of records in DB. I need to do some transactions based on each of them as quickly as possible. I'm using Java EE 6.

```
query.setMaxResults(1000);
List<MyEntity> list = query.getResultList();

while(list != null && !list.isEmpty()){
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        MyEntity entity = list.get(i);
        SomeTransactionMethod(entity);
    }

    list = query.getResultList();
}
```

SomeTransaction method performs `select` on 6 tables and inserts into 1 table. Should I annotate `SomeTransaction` with `@Asynchronous`? If so, how could I wait for all of them to finish so that I can work on next 1000 records?

Comment: I hate PL/SQL as much as the next guy but this may be one of those rare cases where it might be better...

Comment: If you need to update millions of rows, sending them across the wire to your Java program and back again is definitely not the way to go.